# HTML5 video poster not displayed using createObjectURL

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm using a file input to upload a video and I'm creating a preview of it. I create an empty video tag into the DOM and then update the src and poster attributes with the url created using the URL.createObjectURL api.

The video is inserted correctly and if I press play it plays correctly but I don't have the poster displayed.

For the sake of the test I have already in the DOM the video tag and I update the src and

```
function embed(file){
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    $('video').attr('src',url);
    $('video').attr('poster', url);
}
```

The url is a blob:http.... string and I don't understand why I don't see the poster. Is there another way to view the preview withour using the fileReader api since the file is quite large and it would take ages to load it.
thanks

Comment: What, are you trying to use the same URL for `src` and `poster`? How is that supposed to make sense?

Comment: hmm I guess you are right. then how do I extract the first video frame to use it as a poster without loading the entire video?